# SharePoint 2010 workflows will be retired in 2020

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-designer-workflow

Microsoft has announced that it will be ending support this year for the "workflows" component of SharePoint 2010, how is it going to impact on my SharePoint 2010 workflow on-premise? is that mean there is no support but I still can run the workflow? Please advise

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/office-end-of-support-blog/support-update-for-sharepoint-2010-workflows-in-microsoft-365/ba-p/1505453
Microsoft has announced that it will be ending support this year for the "workflows" component of SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 2):

It has no impact on SharePoint on-premise.

It means you cannot run the workflow Starting November 1st.

Starting August 1st, 2020, SharePoint 2010 workflows will be turned off for newly created tenants.

Starting November 1st, 2020, Microsoft will begin to remove the ability to run or create SharePoint 2010 workflows from existing tenants.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will not be able to **run or create** SharePoint 2010 workflows from existing tenants.

Note below points mentioned in the same article:

- Starting August 1st, 2020, **SharePoint 2010 workflows will be turned off** for newly created tenants.
- Starting November 1st, 2020, Microsoft will begin to **remove the ability to run or create SharePoint 2010 workflows** from existing tenants.

Also, if you want to postpone the retirement of the SP 2010 Workflow engine to a more reasonable date then you can vote at: [Postopone Designer 2010 Workflow Engine Retirement](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/330318-sharepoint-administration/suggestions/40856713-postope-designer-2010-workflow-engine-retirement)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the SharePoint 2010 workflows will still run on SharePoint 2010, 2013, 2016 and 2019 on-premises environments.

The turning off announcement is for SharePoint 2010 workflow engine on Microsoft 365.

[image]

Source:https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/office-end-of-support-blog/support-update-for-sharepoint-2010-workflows-in-microsoft-365/ba-p/1505453

Moreover, Microsoft can't remove a module from an on-premises SharePoint without the customer's consent. It can remove the module from future versions. It can also stop the support for that module though.